# Replicating the DataFrame row in a special manner

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replicate data frame rows by splitting the contact number, I'm trying several ways but unable to do so. Please help

Input:

df

```
col1        mob_no             col3
 a    9382949201/3245622535    45
 b    8383459345/4325562678    67
 c    8976247543/1827472398    89
 d    7844329432               09
```

Expected output:

```
col1    mob_no      col3
 a    9382949201     45
 a    3245622535     45
 b    8383459345     67
 b    4325562678     67
 c    8976247543     89
 c    1827472398     89
 d    7844329432     09
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) + [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode):

```
df['mob_no'] = df['mob_no'].str.split('/')
df = df.explode('mob_no')
```

```
  col1      mob_no  col3
0    a  9382949201    45
0    a  3245622535    45
1    b  8383459345    67
1    b  4325562678    67
2    c  8976247543    89
2    c  1827472398    89
3    d  7844329432    09
```